# Bash script, execute command prefixing every line with a given string

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Let's suppose I've a bash script like the one below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start"
do something
git merge blah blah
ant build.xml blah blah blah
echo "end"
```

Obviously the output of the git and ant command is included in the bash output like any other echo.

**Is there any way to achieve something like below?**

```
start
i'm doing something
[GIT] git command output
[GIT] git command output
[GIT] git command output
[GIT] git command output
[ANT] ant command output
[ANT] ant command output
[ANT] ant command output
[ANT] ant command output
[ANT] ant command output
end
```

In case some great person will have a solution I've another little question even if definitely less important.

**Can i also than split the command output if the line is too long?** 
This to avoid something like

```
[ANT] ant command output too long command output too long command output too
long command output too long command output too long
[ANT] ant command output
[ANT] ant command output
```

As i think you noticed i'm trying to tidy up the output of my shells, their are launched through Jenkins and generated by a groovy pipeline script.

**@Yoory & @ghoti:**

Thanks both, the answers are just lovely!

The function is amazing, but unfortunately is a bit hard for me to integrate because it has to interact with other two things that make it a bit hard to read and confusing. Below the exact code, sorry if i did not put it before:

```
git merge --no-ff origin/module 2>&1 | tee -a /merge_files/merge.log
if [ "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" -ne "0" ];
then
    something
else
    other to do..
fi
```

**@Yoory** 
When i try to integrate the function, putting it right before the git command,  the PIPESTATUS returns me always 0 even if the git merge fails, i'm sure it's not so hard to find a solution to it, but as you can see i'm not so skilled with bash.

So for now i'm using the simple sed: | sed 's/^/[GIT] /' or | sed 's/^/[ANT] /'
I tried to integrate fmt with simply piping it with the sad.

```
command | fmt -w 20 | sed "s/^/[ANT] /"
```

The problem is that it works with logs with normal sentences, but it does not work for long strings without space separators (for example a path) cause looks like fmt does not break it the way i'm using, i'm looking at the man to find a parameter that could help me, but i don't think i can achieve it till now.

I did manage to let it work with fmt but fold made the magic for me!

```
 command | fold -w 138 | sed "s/^/[ANT] /"
```

Thanks to everyone for the help, and if you want to add any feedback i would like to hear them, code and learn!

Comment: `git merge blah | sed 's/^/[GIT] /'` and `ant build.xml blah | sed 's/^/[ANT] /'` ?

Comment: Oh, and `man fmt` in your operating system to see how you might split long lines.

Comment: Per your update, if you can explain more about what you're looking for with regard to return codes, perhaps we can help. I don't quite understand what's confusing.

Comment: ivoru, I've updated my answer to address wrapping long lines and return code of executed command. Absolute paths are handled in @ghoti's answer. Do you have any other issues with this approach?

Comment: Don't know what could be wrong with return code. When I execute `prefix_output false hello` both `echo $?` and `echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}` return `1` as expected, and with `prefix_output true hello` they return `0`.

Comment: Hi Yoory I'll try to investigate better, but I'm sure of it, cause if i keep the prefix method the pipeline return always 0 instead if i put it out it returns 0 just if the merge command works and return 1 if it fails... it sounds trange to me too

Answer (score 5):

The first solution that came to mind:

```
function prefix_output {
    local prefix=$1
    prefix=${prefix^^}
    "${@}" 2>&1 | while read -r line; do
        printf "[%s] %s\n" "${prefix}" "${line}"
    done
    return ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
}
```

Use this way:

```
prefix_output git merge blah blah
prefix_output ant build.xml blah blah blah
```

Also updated version now respects return status of executed command. The following will work:

```
prefix_output git merge blah blah && echo success || echo failure
```

To address wrapping too long lines, there is a modified version that uses `fmt` (inspired by others answers):

```
function prefix_output {
    local prefix=$1
    prefix=${prefix^^}
    "${@}" 2>&1 | fmt -w 80 | while read -r line; do
        printf "[%s] %s\n" "${prefix}" "${line}"
    done
    return ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
}
```

I've tested it on simple commands, tell me if it doesn't work for some more complex cases.

Comment: Nice, though I'd let printf do the formatting. `printf '[%s] %s\n' "${1^^}" "$line"`.

Comment: @ghoti, thanks! Don't know what was on my mind to use printf and format the string by hand :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a variation on Yoory's excellent function:

```
function prefix {
    local prefix="${1##*/}"             # strip leading path
    prefix=${prefix^^}                  # use upper case
    while read -r line; do              # read lines...
        printf "[%s] %s\n" "${prefix}" "${line}"
    done < <("${@}" 2>&1 | fmt -w 42)   # wrap at 42 columns
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ prefix /bin/echo {1..31}
[ECHO] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
[ECHO] 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Here's a short little function, which uses `paste`, `fmt`, and
   `bash` to print the first 5 letters of a command, (as so not to
   exceed the width of a *tab*), followed by an indented *60* character
   wrap of that command's output:

   ```
   indent_command() { paste <(echo "[${1:0:5}]") <($@ | fmt -w 60) ; }
   ```

   Demo using `yes` with various endless outputs, and `head` to limit
   that:

   ```
   for f in yes no maybe ; do indent_command yes $f | head -3 ; done
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   [yes]   yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes
           yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes
           yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes
   [yes]   no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no
           no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no
           no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no
   [yes]   maybe maybe maybe maybe maybe maybe maybe maybe maybe
           maybe maybe maybe maybe maybe maybe maybe maybe maybe
           maybe maybe maybe maybe maybe maybe maybe maybe maybe maybe
   ```

   ---

   This variation makes `indent_command` prefix the command name in
   upper case, and reformats only the long lines:

   ```
   indent_command() { n="$1" n="${n^^}"; 
                      paste <(echo "[${n:0:5}]") <($@ | fmt -sw 60) ; }
   ```

   The output becomes:

   ```
   [YES]   yes
           yes
           yes
   [YES]   no
           no
           no
   [YES]   maybe
           maybe
           maybe
   ```
2. *GNU* `sed` method, using prefixes on every line, and char based wrapping,
   (cuts words in the middle):

   ```
   indent_with_sed() { $@ | sed -E 's/(.{0,60})/['"${1^^}"'] \1/g;
                                    s/(.)(\['"${1^^}"'] )/\1\n\2/g' ; }
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   indent_with_sed echo foo{1..30}
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   [ECHO] foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4 foo5 foo6 foo7 foo8 foo9 foo10 foo11 foo
   [ECHO] 12 foo13 foo14 foo15 foo16 foo17 foo18 foo19 foo20 foo21 foo
   [ECHO] 22 foo23 foo24 foo25 foo26 foo27 foo28 foo29 foo30
   ```